# syslog error message eating up my HD with wireless message

Tags: networking, syslog

I received a message that I ran out of space on my hard drive, so I deleted a few things, large games I never played, etc, a few hours later, I got the same message, so I deleted a few more large things, and without doing anything, I was rapidly running out of HD space.  I finally tracked the problem down to a 16 gb syslog file and an 11 gb syslog.1 file.  I opened it up and got this repeating message:

```
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: dbus_g_proxy_cancel_call: assertion 'pending != NULL' failed
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: nl80211: Driver  does not support authentication/association or connect commands
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Cannot assign requested address
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: <error>  [1402608755.122976] [nm-supplicant-interface.c:997] interface_add_cb():  (wlan0): error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this  interface.
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: dbus_g_proxy_cancel_call: assertion 'pending != NULL' failed
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: nl80211: Driver  does not support authentication/association or connect commands
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Cannot assign requested address
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: <error>  [1402608755.123542] [nm-supplicant-interface.c:997] interface_add_cb():  (wlan0): error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this  interface.
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: dbus_g_proxy_cancel_call: assertion 'pending != NULL' failed
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: nl80211: Driver  does not support authentication/association or connect commands
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Cannot assign requested address
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L wpa_supplicant[1064]: wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
Jun 12 17:32:35 adam-EP35-DS3L NetworkManager[944]: <error>  [1402608755.124093] [nm-supplicant-interface.c:997] interface_add_cb():  (wlan0): error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this  interface.
```

Any idea how to solve this?  FYI, although I've used ubuntu for a little while now, I'm still a noob, so please be detailed.

Comment: descrive system specifications and the os version

Comment: I just dealt with this problem (and I'm still trying).

For now, after removing `wpa_supplicant` and adding manually the wlan0 configuration to `/etc/network/interfaces` I could delete some logs and have the system back.

I'm leaving this tip here. Not a good answer, but might help you. I'll keep an eye here for other better answers as well.